# How to listen to jquery-ui events within a Marionette.ItemView

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, marionette

I do have some dynamically loaded ItemViews that load into layout regions. The templates contain jquery-ui components, e.g. a slider '#mySlider'. I do initialize the component with the Maronette.Region onShow event. My view looks like this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: '#my-tpl',

  initialize: function() {
     _.bindAll(this);
  },

  onShow: function(){
   $('#mySlider').slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      //some code here to update the the Views model, like
      //this.model.set({'stroke': ui.value});
   }});

  .....
```

Obviously this does not work, because the this.model is not defined like so within #mySlider. How do I properly do this and capture the jquery-ui events as as Marionette.ItemView event?

Answer (score 2):

A simple closure will do.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/z7QsC/

```
var SliderView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#slide-template",
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this);
    },
    onShow: function() {            
      var self = this; 

      $('#slider-range').slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        slide: self.updateSlider
      });
    },
    updateSlider: function(event, ui) {
        this.model.set({'stroke': ui.value});
    }
});
```

Comment: This is perfect and so simple!